# How to repeat the "replace" command where there is dynamic input and dynamic output?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace the coefficients in 625 equations.

I am trying to replace

- x(2) with x(1)
- x(3) with x(2)
- …
- x(625) with x(624)

Here is my code.

```
Sub FindReplaceAll()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim fnd As Variant
    Dim rplc As Variant

    'To Replace the x(2) with x(1) and x(2) with x(1) and .... x(625) with x(624)

    For k = 2 To 625       
        fnd = "x(k)"
        rplc = "x(k-1)"
        For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            sht.Cells.Replace What:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
                              LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
                              MatchCase:=False, _
                              SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        Next sht
    Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: What's with the `With`?  You need `fnd = "x(" & k & ")"` otherwise you are literally searching for the string "x(k)". Ditto `rplc`.

Comment: Thank you got it...

Comment: @SJR I find a problem with this code, When i perform 

For k = 25 To 624
fnd = "x(" & k & ")"
rplc = "x(" & k + 1 & ")"

 ' It is replacing entire coefficents x(25).x(26),x(27)...  with  x(625) only

Comment: Yes well when you think about it, 24 will be replaced by 25 which will be replaced by 26 etc. So you'll have to work backwards, 624 -> 625, 623 -> 624 etc.